# Next.js PWA, IOS pull to refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app written in Next.js. Everything works perfectly, but the pull to refresh doesn't work on IOS. Is there a way to enable it?

It works in Safari but doesn't work on PWA.

Comment: Doesn't related to react.js or next.js, this is a general problem for iOS PWA.